# My Toast message is not translated; it's displayed in the default language only

Tags: android, android-toast

I created a Toast message to inform user about device orientation change:

```
if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.orientation_change, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        recreate();
    }
```

The message is displayed whenever needed, but in other language versions of my app the `R.string.orientation_change` text is displayed in default language, which is English. This was checked in emulator and real devices, same result in each.

Is there any way to make the Toast message localized?

Comment: This should not help... But did you try to use getResources().getString(R.string.orientation_change) instead? Only text displayed in Toast is failing?

Comment: The same outcome, unfortunately... The Toast gets displayed, but in English when it should be in German.

Comment: The structure is correct: there was an error while building the project and Lint didn't spot that there was a `translatable="false"` flag set in the default string file - please see the summary posted as an answer.

Comment: Nice... Good to know!!!

Answer (score 2):

Might feel like a hack, but get the resources to do the translation for you, rather than internal Toast code.

```
Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.orientation_change), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Translated text is located in `values` directories. The method should look for the text in there, but it only takes English values.

Comment: Is the values directory not representing the default language being English?  Are you trying to get it to display the string from the values-es (or other language) directory?  Maybe including your strings.xml files might help.

Comment: There was something wrong with Lint checks, but I got it solved - please take a look at my summary posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide one string for each language you want to support, following this structure:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Additional info, please refer: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: Checked the structure and it looks the same way in my case.

Comment: Of course you entered with translated text on all these XMLs, yes? And if your default language is PL, you have to make a **value-XX** folder where *XX* is the sign of the language you're testing, yes too? And how you are testing all of this, you change the language of your mobile and restart the app? Thank you.

Comment: All the checks you pointed out were fulfilled, the problem was with Lint - I published the summary as an answer, please check.

Answer (score 2):

Got it fixed:

1. Cleaned the Project;
2. Built the Project again.

While building, I received an error that `translatable="false"` parameter was set next to the value defined in English, although there were values prepared for other languages too.

For some reason Lint didn't spot it before but anyway, the problem is solved now.

Thank you guys for your efforts.